# How to plot Splines with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, splines

I have some data that i want to make a histogram of.  However, I want to represent this histogram with line.  I have tried using the `freq_poly` of the `ggplot2`.  However, the line produced is pretty jagged.  I want to know if it is possible to use the `splines` with `ggplot2`, so that the line produced in `freq_poly` will be smoother.

```
d <- rnorm( 1000 )
h <- hist( d, breaks="FD", plot=F )
plot( spline( h$mids, h$counts ), type="l" )
```

This is what i want to accomplish.  But I want to do it using `ggplot2`.

Comment: Some combination of `geom_smooth` and `geom_density` are probably what you want.  Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are trying to use the `spline()` function. If not, disregard this answer.

`spline()` returns a list object of two components, x and y:

```
List of 2
 $ x: num [1:93] -3.3 -3.23 -3.17 -3.1 -3.04 ...
 $ y: num [1:93] 1 0.1421 -0.1642 -0.0228 0.4294 ...
```

We can simply turn these into a data.frame and plot them There may be a fancier ways to do this, but this will work:

```
h <- hist( d, breaks="FD", plot=F )
zz <- spline( h$mids, h$counts )
qplot(x, y, data = data.frame(x = zz$x, y = zz$y), geom = "line")
```

Comment: This is a good answer, I should have though about this.  The only problem is this does not necessarily produce a smooth line the way `spline` produces.